# Windows Service - notification

Tags: python, windows, service

I am writting a Python Windows-service, that downloads some files and stores them in folder chosen by user.
The problem is that I want to inform user about new download completition, preferably with notification from here:
https://gist.github.com/wontoncc/1808234

But somehow it doesn't work... End with error:

```
(0, 'Shell_NotifyIcon', 'No error message is available')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows service hasn't interaction with the desktop. Therefore you can't do it directly. You can create some other windows application that will communicate with the service and provide you the UX.

Comment: Roger that. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058958/python-execute-command-in-windows-service